# Is it possible for unpaid job to get an visa? I want to find a research assistant position in USA or Canada but I am in another country?

Tags: working-visas, job-hunting

I have a Master’s degree, and want to apply for PhD. I want to find a position during the gap year. It is also possible to do 2 years. But I am not in USA or Canada. So, How do I find a research assistant position? **Is it possible for unpaid job to get an visa?**

Comment: Note that this is an exact duplicate of a question in academia. I answered the first half of the question regarding academics. Answers here should focus on the issue of visas for unpaid jobs.

Comment: @RoboKaren Thanks for the reminder. I have edit the question and the content

Comment: There are severe limits to 'unpaid' jobs in the United States. We have a long bitter, tragic and complicated history with the concept. I seriously doubt you will even find an unpaid job that lasts a year, much less a visa for such.

Comment: @ouflak actually, if the work is typically unpaid, it can be done in visitor status. But since research assistants are typically paid, they require a visa type that allows employment, even if they have an unpaid position.